# Changing URL alias of webform breaks template

Tags: 7, theming, webforms

I created a webform with a URL alias of `contact-us`. The edit URL is `http://local.mysite.com/node/1/webform`. I have two custom templates, `page--node--1.tpl.php` and `webform-form.tpl.php`. Everything works correctly.

Now I've been asked to change the URL alias of the page to `feedback`. As soon as I do this, the form stops displaying. I've error-logged things out, and when the alias is changed, it's not getting to the `webform-form.tpl.php`.

I'm confused - I understood that `webform-form.tpl.php` (without a specific form name) would be applied to any and all webforms. Is this incorrect? Or is there something else I'm missing that would cause a URL change to break this way?

Edited to add that there are no changes to `template.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which template name Drupal suggests after you changed URL alias.

Enable debug option so you could see template name suggestions (they shown in the html source as commented out strings).

You should see something like this:
[image]

In your case the new suggestion could be: 
webform-form--feedback.tpl.php or page--feedback.tpl.php